# Practical Way to Detect a Markov Chain is Regular Given the Transition Matrix

Tags: markov-chains

I understand that a Markov Chain is reducible if, given its transition matrix $P$, there exists $n$ such that every element of $P^n$ is greater than 0.

However, I am wondering that if there is an fast and practical way to detect a Markov chain is regular numerically.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to determining whether a graph is connected?  Wikipedia [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_%28graph_theory%29#Computational_aspects) the standard algorithm is breadth-first search.

Comment: **regular**, not **reducible**

Comment: In addition to the directed graph being strongly connected, it has to be aperiodic.  For this (given that it is strongly connected) it is necessary and sufficient that for some states $s$ and $t$, there are walks from $s$ to $t$ with lengths that are relatively prime.